# Estimating SOC using coulomb counting with DSP

Tags: batteries, c, dsp, soc

I am trying to estimate the SOC of a battery using the Coulomb Counting technique. I am implementing the following equation on a DSP inside PSIM:
$$
SOC[K] = SOC[K-1] - \frac{I_{Bat}}{Q_{Bat}}\cdot{Ts}
$$

```
//Performed at T=0 of the simulation
double SOC[2] = {0.0, 0.7};
double Ts = 1/12000.0;

//Performed on each simulation step
I_Bat = in[2];
SOC[0] = SOC[1] - (I_Bat/(2.5/2000.0))*Ts/(3600.0);
out[1] = SOC[0];
SOC[1] = SOC[0];
```

The initial state of charge of the battery is 0.7. The results I am getting, however, are not very precise:
[image: Actual SOC in red. Estimated SOC in blue.]

Actual SOC in red. Estimated SOC in blue.

Am I missing something in my implementation or is there a way to increase its accuracy? Thanks for your time.

Update: I am gathering the I and Q as follows:
[image]

For *I* I am sensing the battery's current with a gain of 1. And as for *Q* I am using the battery's nominal capacity.

Comment: Well you have to be missing something else you'd get the same result. As for accuracy, it largely depends on how you monitor I and Q and you don't show this information.

Comment: @Andyaka I've updated the post with the information you requested. Thanks

Comment: How are you monitoring load current and into what load? I'm not going to ask again.

Comment: @Raph, you've hidden your schematic. It also looks like your off by a scaling factor.

Comment: How are you accounting for SoC variations caused by temperature, SoH, and internal parasitics? All of those play a major role in coulombic efficiency. Measuring SoC accurately is rough...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, trying to estimate the SOC with only a current-based method is not going to be precise since there are other variables you're not accounting for.

Coulomb counting relies on **integration**  and that is its main drawback -- any measurement offset, error, or otherwise uncertainty grows without bounds over time until you reset the estimate.

Your basic equation is correct but imagine what happens if the current measurement device has an offset (e.g \$I_{\text{OFFSET}}\$):

Your equation now becomes:

$$ \text{SOC[n]} = \text{SOC[n-1]}-\dfrac{I_{\text{BAT}}+I_{\text{OFFSET}}}{Q}\Delta T $$
$$ \text{SOC[n]} = \text{SOC[n-1]}-\dfrac{I_{\text{BAT}}}{Q}\Delta T +\epsilon $$

Where

$$\epsilon= -\dfrac{I_{\text{OFFSET}}}{Q}\Delta T$$

You can see how this error term propagates through each SOC estimate and in fact, for \$n\$ measurements, the **cumulative** error is

$$\text{Error[n] = }n\cdot \epsilon$$

The source of the error could be one thing or a combination of many other effects such as model error, measurement error, uncertainty, etc. I don't know the specifics of your model but for this method to work better, you need to somehow take them into account and "reset" the integral error that will continue to grow to such a point that the true and the estimate diverge significantly.